# Link Dependant Classes but Not Extend

Tags: php, class

I have two PHP classes, `ResultCounter` and `ResultDetail`, the first is dependent on the second, but the the second is not dependent on the first. It struck me that these classes should be linked formally somehow, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I thought about making the first a subclass of the second, but this doesn't work as the first has many (but a finite number of) instances of the second.

Here's the basics of both classes to give you an idea of what I'm talking about.

```
class ResultCounter {
    private $W;
    private $L;
    private $D;
    private $T;
    private $A;
    private $X;
    private $B1;
    private $B2;

    function __construct() {
        $this->W = new ResultDetail;
        $this->L = new ResultDetail;
        $this->D = new ResultDetail;
        $this->T = new ResultDetail;
        $this->A = new ResultDetail;
        $this->X = new ResultDetail;
        $this->B1 = new ResultDetail;
        $this->B2 = new ResultDetail;
    }

    // some other functions
}

class ResultDetail {
    public $count = 0;
    public $batfirst;
    public $batsecond;

    // some functions but don't ever reference ResultCounter
}
```

It is required to sometimes have a separate instance of `ResultDetail` in the project as well.

Is there a way of linking these classes so that `ResultCounter` is explicitly dependent on `ResultDetail`? Is defining the instances in the constructor enough, or should I just not worry about this?

Comment: Tight coupling (which you already have) is generally considered poor practice. Why you would want to add a further 'link'? I would instead go the other way and consider having the `ResultCounter` class take an `IResultDetailFactory` in the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it. In any application classes will depend on other classes. If they're kept in the same source tree then it will generally be assumed that they are likely to be dependent. In any case, if `ResultDetail` were missing for any reason, when someone tried to construct a `ResultCounter`, then PHP would give them an error saying that it couldn't find `ResultDetail`.